# How do I sort a range of lines in a file automatically on save?

Tags: file, sorting, vim

I have a file with a header and some sorted lines, separated by a blank line:

```
# header line 1
# header line 2
# ...

line 1 
line 2
...
```

How do I sort everything after the header in Vim? Also, how can I make Vim sort the file automatically on each save?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sort the lines after a blank line in a file you can use the [`:sort`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asort) command with a range (remember that ranges may use *patterns* too):

```
:/^$/+1;$sort
```

To make Vim do this every time the file is saved you could use an [autocommand](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html). Add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWritePre /path/to/file :/^$/+1;$sort
```